# Wrong values when reading floats from a text file in c

Tags: c, file, scanf

I am reading text file contains values like below

> 125602365  119653955   126374444   124463807   127312438   128395899

and the below code to read it.

```
if(!(pvtcheck(0)))
  {
     fscanf(fp,"%f",&deltime);
     printf("\ndeltime0=%f\n",deltime);    ///Actual value is 125602365, but i am getting 125602368.
  }

  if(!(pvtcheck(1)))
  {
      fscanf(fp,"\t%f",&deltime); 
      printf("\ndeltime1=%f\n",deltime);///Actual value is 119653955, but i am getting 119653952.
  }
  /// same for pvtcheck(2),pvtcheck(3),pvtcheck(4)
  if(!(pvtcheck(5)))
  {
      fscanf(fp,"\t%f",&deltime);
       printf("\ndeltime5=%f\n",deltime); ///Actual value is 128395899, but i am getting 128395896.
  }
```

In the Comment i have written output , any solution to not change the values

Comment: What is the type of `deltime`? Please learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: On a couple of unrelated notes: You don't need all the parentheses in the condition expressions, e.g. `if (!pvtcheck(0))` should be enough. Also, instead of doing the same thing three times in the `if` bodies, do all common things first and then use conditions to do the things that differ. Lastly, the tab `"\t"` in the `fscanf` format isn't needed.

Comment: Please learn about formatting or don't try (many users are happy to help with formatting), your attempts have broken C-syntax. Learning about indentation would also be helpful.

Comment: Please study and apply the concept of making a [mcve].

Comment: Please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). And again, please learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I also recommend you read [this Stack Overflow question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). And all of http://idownvotedbecau.se/ to learn some reasons your question are getting negative votes. Specific examples include http://idownvotedbecau.se/nomcve/ and http://idownvotedbecau.se/beingunresponsive.

Comment: @Rishi, Your code is too poor to help you. Could you please post your full source code?

Comment: Please post the complete code of the function, with the definition of `deltime`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the `double` type instead of `float`, and the `%lf` format specifier for `scanf` instead of `%f`.

```
double deltime;

fscanf(fp, "%lf", &deltime);
printf("\ndeltime0=%lf\n", deltime);
fscanf(fp, "\t%lf", &deltime);
printf("\ndeltime1=%f\n", deltime);
...
```

BTW: for `printf` you can use either `%f` or `%lf` they both have the same meaning.

Also read [this SO article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)

Comment: Nice refererence!

Comment: @unwind There is `%lf`, it has the same meaning as `%f`. See section 7.21.6.1 of the C Standard ("The fprintf function")

Comment: @M.M Thanks, I only checked the man page and it's of course less complete.